# GPIO.input in a while loop without sleep

Tags: gpio

I need to catch a fast GPIO pulse in a while loop like so

```
while True:
    if GPIO.input(11) == 1:
        sys.exit(0)
```

the pulse is so fast (magnet passing by a switch), that if I add a sleep in the while, of just even `.5`, it will miss the value in some cases.. without one, even with an internal pulldown, it will get a random false 1 pretty much instantly.. Is there some way to remove the sleep, and have it reliable? Is this something ony an external pulldown would solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polling for input, in any language, is a poor solution.

Python makes it simple to catch interrupts e.g.

```
    # set an interrupt on a falling edge and wait for it to happen
    GPIO.wait_for_edge(INT, GPIO.FALLING)
```

NOTE this blocks the process, until an interrupt occurs, so it is best to do it on a background process.

Answer (score 5):

Any GPIO library you choose to use will almost certainly provide an interrupt capability.

Use that interrupt capability to inform you when the GPIO level changes from 0 to 1 (rising edge), or from 1 to 0 (falling edge) or on either change.

By the way I've used Hall effect sensors to detect magnets spinning on a shaft at about 9000 RPM (from memory).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the application you may want to consider a hardware solution. You can detect a very brief pulse and use that to trigger a monostable that communicates with the Pi. External hardware can do signal-conditioning and cope with things like contact-bounce in switches. How clean is your input signal?